# Circular Dependency Problem in JPA entities: SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, circular-dependency

I am working on a Spring Boot + MySQL project. I intend to develop a feature:

1. There are several stages, A,B,C,D,E,....
2. There are two entities `X` and `Y` who can perform some actions which would cause transition from one stage to another.
3. The actions are given as different entities associated with the stages--an action can be taken when on a particular stage and that action will cause a transition to another stage (represented by `associatedStage`).
4. Every action is associated with a stage and every action may / may not cause a transition to another stage (represented by `nextStage`).

**CustomerAction.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer_action")
public class CustomerAction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "customer_action_id")
    private UUID customerActionId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "associated_stage_id", referencedColumnName = "stage_id", nullable = false)
    private Stage associatedStage;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "next_stage_id", referencedColumnName = "stage_id", nullable = true)
    private Stage nextStage;
}
```

**AgentAction.java**

```
@Table
@Entity(name="agent_action")
public class AgentAction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name="agent_action_id")
    private UUID agentActionId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="associated_stage_id",referencedColumnName = "stage_id",nullable = false)
    private Stage associatedStage;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="next_stage_id",referencedColumnName = "stage_id",nullable = true)
    private Stage nextStage;
}
```

**Stage.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stage")
public class Stage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "stage_id")
    private UUID stageId;

    @Column(name = "stage_name",nullable = false)
    private String stageName;

    @Column(name = "stage_actor",nullable = false)
    @Enumerated
    private StageActor stageActor; //customer and agent

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stage",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "associatedStage", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<CustomerAction> customerActions = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "associatedStage", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<AgentAction> agentActions = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stage",cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH},orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<WorkflowStage> workflowStages=new HashSet<>();

}
```

[image]

The `Stage` and `CustomerAction/AgentAction` entities have two separate relationships, causing a kind of circular dependency. The `action` entities are holding two properties of type `Stage`.

I don't know if I am following best practices or whether I should go ahead with this.

What is a better approach?